# NSDictionary / Base64 String Logs

Tags: ios, image, base64, nsdictionary, nsdata

I have this weird problem about NSDictionary and base64 String and I cannot locate where the problem is. 
Here's the code:

```
  NSData *pictureData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]);
    NSString * picture = [pictureData base64EncodedString];
    picture = [picture stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
    if(picture == nil){
        picture = @"";
    }

self.postDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:picture,@"picture",@"some text",@"caption", nil];
```

What happens is If I log the string,"picture", the log is very fine and okay. 
But when I try logging the dictionary it says something like this

```
{
caption = "some text";
picture = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAABYCAIAAADqXdEfAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAHGlET1QAAAACAAAAAAAAACwAAAAoAAAALAAAACwAAI2cl9ZnZQAAQABJREFUeAGM3euyXVl5HmDdWa7EuYec7sDBlZSrErtS+RP/clXiuCr+YzAYaKDpBmPABpr0S...and it gets CUT some part then... picture = iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAABYCAIAAADqXdEfAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAHGlET1QAAAACAAAAAAAAACwAAAAoAAA..till the end of the base64 string";
}
```

***The problem is the word "picture" as key is found also in the string object inside picture. The base64 string was cut first then followed by the picture = then the full text of the base64 string***

Does not happen on simulator but happens on device. Before was just fine. I didn't changed anything on the codes. and I cannot change the NSDictionary codes also.

If I don't log it it's still like that when the web service receives the POST.

So if you guys can help me find a way. Thanks :)

Comment: can you please point out what's wrong in dictionary print

Comment: see in the print of picture there's a picture inside it also and another equal sign. but on the print of string NSLog(@"%@",picture);
This doesn't happen. everything is the full string of the base64.

Comment: @Iducool have you encountered a bug something like this?